# Convert Html to Pdf in flurry background

Tags: php

I used  several search and methods to find this convertion from html to pdf
but I didn't got. What is the way to convert an HTML page to PDF? I already downloaded `tcpdf library` but I don't how I to use it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will need to render the HTML page using a layout engine, which I'm not sure if that is possible in just PHP

Comment: use MPDF instead it will convert HTML to PDF and it support lots of CSS properties.

Comment: After creating html pass you html in `$tcpdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');` function. as I have mentioned you take reference `TCPDF` examples.

Comment: i download and copy paste the tcpdf folder in my application folder  , then what is the next step , which php file i import into my page

Comment: hey roopendra i create a php page which uses flurry datas and high charts , now i want  to convert it into pdf format, when the user clicks the page datas should be downloadble as pdf i put a link download pdf . pls help me

Comment: Hi Nishil if you want to convert your simple html into pdf then you can use my below example. But as you mention you want to convert high charts into pdf then you should use TCPDF example 31 here is the example of PDF and PHP code http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_031.pdf , http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_031.phps

Comment: roopendra how i can remove that tcpdf header from pdf i remove $pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 006');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide'); parts

Comment: As I have mentioned in my answer you can change tcpdf constant like header information from `tcpdf/config/tcpdf_config.php`

Comment: got it i get thanks roopendra

Comment: hey roopendra it is just creating using queries but i have already charts in my page , then how convertion ?

Comment: I didn't get you Nishil, can you please explain me.

Comment: Are you asking how to create html data to pass in `writeHtml()` function ?

Comment: i think you r partially right. i want to select data from a div that div contain my charts, datas and tables in php, example $('div_name').html(); in jquery, then how we can select data in php like in jquery

Comment: You can get html of an div using .html() function , please refer `http://api.jquery.com/html/` link

Comment: that i know roopendra then how we can select the contants of div in php  like in jquery, pls answer

Answer (score 0):

Please Use **tcpdf** , try example 6 in **tcpdf** examples link http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php

**try this example :**

```
require_once('write path to include /config/lang/eng.php');
require_once('write path to include tcpdf.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 006');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 006', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));


//set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

//set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

//set some language-dependent strings
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// writeHTML($html, $ln=true, $fill=false, $reseth=false, $cell=false, $align='')
// writeHTMLCell($w, $h, $x, $y, $html='', $border=0, $ln=0, $fill=0, $reseth=true, $align='', $autopadding=true)

// create some HTML content
$html = 'Write your html code here';

// output the HTML content
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

$this->pdf->lastPage();
ob_clean();
//Close and output PDF document
$this->pdf->Output($filename, 'D'); //D if you want download it use I if you want open it on new tab
```

Change constant value e.g PDF_HEADER_LOGO from **tcpdf/config/tcpdf_config.php**

Answer (score 0):

Use TCPDF

Please download tcpdf and extrat it and put it in your application folder

And in the page that you need to convert pdf please add html part need to show in pdf into a variable

eg: 
    $data = "Hello World";
    /*include tcpdf here*/

```
$tcpdf = new TCPDF();
$textfont = 'helvetica';


$tcpdf->SetAuthor("Julia Holland");
$tcpdf->SetAutoPageBreak(true);

$tcpdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$tcpdf->setPrintFooter(false);

$tcpdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 0);
$tcpdf->SetFont($textfont,'',9);

$tcpdf->AddPage();

$tcpdf->writeHTML($data, true, 0, true, 0);
$tcpdf->Output('filename11.pdf', 'I');
```

Now you can use custom fonts,style etch that are listed in tcpdf site and this one prints Hello world in pdf

download tcpdf from here http://www.tcpdf.org/

Comment: Assign your html page need to render as pdf into $data in above example

Comment: i already created data and html elements without using $data then how ?

Comment: You just need to assign that created data into $data, because $data we are passing into tcpdf to render as pdf.So if you are already cretaed the html like this <div class="pdf">data to show</div> just assign it as $data = '<div class="pdf">data to show</div>';

Comment: hi sanjay , i have already charts in page when the user clciks these created charts and data (using flurry , datas)  want to converted into pdf

Comment: Yes you need to pass that data into page that render as pdf and make that into html. Html is converted into pdf .In tcpdf document you get many examples to customize the pdf and its layout

Comment: i got one example which creates charts dynamically and convert into pdf, but my need is , i have already charts, datas and tables that i need to convert when user clicks a link called download pdf

Comment: yes TCPDF work like that first convert and available to download.. and it is not already created one create at the time you click on the link

Comment: how i get html data in php ? that i want to convert into pdf, pls answer

Comment: <?php $data = '<put your html >';  ?>put your html dada inside quotes and assign it into $data variable

Comment: hey sanjay i want to get data from a div example we can select data using jquery as $('div_name').html(); , then how we can select like this using php

Comment: Not clear what you actually needs. If you have a data in your <div_name> you just need to put that $data = '<div_name>';just assign the html created into $data

Answer (score 0):

Use the simple or advanced API from [htm2pdf.co.uk](http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk/features)

Comment: how  ? pls tell me the steps

Comment: pls see their website for full info

Answer (score 0):

follow this link http://www.tcpdf.org/
and try this

```
<?php
// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
require_once('../lib/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

// extend TCPF with custom functions
class MYPDF extends TCPDF {


    // Colored table
    public function ColoredTable($header,$data) {
        // Colors, line width and bold font
        $this->SetFillColor(255, 0, 0);
        $this->SetTextColor(255);
        $this->SetDrawColor(128, 0, 0);
        $this->SetLineWidth(0.3);
        $this->SetFont('', 'B');
        // Header
        $w = array(40, 35, 40, 45);
        $num_headers = count($header);
        for($i = 0; $i < $num_headers; ++$i) {
            $this->Cell($w[$i], 7, $header[$i], 1, 0, 'C', 1);
        }
        $this->Ln();
        // Color and font restoration
        $this->SetFillColor(224, 235, 255);
        $this->SetTextColor(0);
        $this->SetFont('');
        // Data
        $fill = 0;
        foreach($data as $row) {
            $this->Cell($w[0], 6, $row[0], 'c');
            $this->Cell($w[1], 6, $row[1], 'c');
            $this->Cell($w[2], 6, number_format($row[2]), 'LR', 0, 'R', $fill);
            $this->Cell($w[3], 6, number_format($row[3]), 'LR', 0, 'R', $fill);
            $this->Ln();
            $fill=!$fill;
        }
        $this->Cell(array_sum($w), 0, '', 'T');
    }
}

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new MYPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 011');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

// set default header data
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, PDF_HEADER_TITLE.' 011', PDF_HEADER_STRING);

// set header and footer fonts
$pdf->setHeaderFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN));
$pdf->setFooterFont(Array(PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA));

// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);

// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);

// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
$lg = Array();
$lg['a_meta_charset'] = 'UTF-8';
$lg['a_meta_dir'] = 'rtl';
$lg['a_meta_language'] = 'fa';
$lg['w_page'] = 'page';

// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
$pdf->setLanguageArray($lg);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// set font
$pdf->SetFont('aealarabiya', '', 18);

// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();

// column titles
$header = array('Country', 'Capital', 'Area (sq km)', 'Pop. (thousands)');

// data loading
$data = array('data1'  , 'data2'  , '323' , '243');

// print colored table
$pdf->ColoredTable($header, $data);

// ---------------------------------------------------------

// close and output PDF document
ob_end_clean();
$pdf->Output('example_011.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please realize this question dates from early 2013 (almost 3 years ago). You can still answer of course, especially when new tools / libraries / versions are available and open room to new and better solutions. In that case, please detail the reasons why you think your answer would outperform the ones already provided.