# TCPDF and PHP: Convert large number of printable HTML items to PDF

Tags: php, pdf, printing, tcpdf

I have vouchers in my PHP web-application which user can print them one by one inside browser.
Now I need a tool to add 10,000 vouchers with the same layout to a PDF file (for bundle printing).
I spend a lot of time to make vouchers printable layout and I don't want to spend time to make them as combination of different elements such as rows,graphics, ... to be added separately to a PDF file.

I want to know are there any specific methods to use TCPDF and add vouchers to a pdf file and It can automatically generate output file? Please consider that number of vouchers are large and I don't want to display them inside one browser page and then render them for printing.

I saw a solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14393819/1080355), but one of my challenges is that I don't know how many of vouchers may fit inside one page and I need that library handle it automatically.

If you have another solution I would be helpful to hear that.

Comment: Have you considered [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) ? You can create vouchers in pure html/css (one voucher per page using css to seprate them) and print them out with a single command without displaying in browser. Check [mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/mikehaertl/phpwkhtmltopdf)

Answer (score 0):

use web browser Chrom in console

for CentOS install

```
yum install chromium
```

Use it

```
/usr/lib64/chromium-browser/chromium-browser --headless --print-to-pdf=./my.pdf https://google.com
```